# Record a variable array as it is at a given moment, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

In the following code, I want `oneArray` to remain what it is when it's declared, namely `[1, 2, 3]`. Instead, it changes when `myArray` changes. Is there a way to prevent this?

```
let myArray = [1, 2, 3];
const oneArray = myArray;

console.log(myArray);
console.log(oneArray);

myArray.pop(); // When myArray changes, so does oneArray.

console.log(myArray);
console.log(oneArray);
```

I tried using `const` as opposed to `let`, but as you can see, it does not solve the problem. Being a beginner, I didn't know what else to try.

Comment: Specifically for array of numbers, you can copy them with `array.slice()`, without arguments

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine - or, any array of any combination of primitives

Comment: That first answer in the duplicate is good for your use-case (creating a shallow copy of the array). However, if you ever have an array of _objects_ for example, [`structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) provides a way to deep-copy that data too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that both your arrays are changing at the same time is because they are pointing to the same object. In order to have the arrays be totally seperate, you should use the spread operator. This will create a new object for oneArray to point to. Ex

```
oneArray = [...myArray]
```